# Handle keyboard return action for UITextFiled inside UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UIcollectionView` with sections. `CollectionView` Cell consist of a `UITextFiled`. I have create a keyboard `inputAccessoryView` with two arrow buttons as below.

Now my requirement is when user press the arrow buttons, next textfield should become first responder. I am struggling how to get currently selected textfield instance and the next one because the textfield is generate dynamically inside `CollectionView` Cell. Please share some ideas how to achieve this.

[image]

CollectionView Cell class

```
@implementation ItemCell

@synthesize txtTitle;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        txtTitle = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 60.0, 30.0)];
        [txtTitle setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];

        UIToolbar* keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
        [keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];

        UIBarButtonItem *prevBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@"<" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(prevButtonPressed)];

        UIBarButtonItem *nextBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@">" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextButtonPressed)];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                          target:nil action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                          initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                          target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];
        keyboardToolbar.items = @[prevBarButton, nextBarButton, flexBarButton, doneBarButton];
        self.txtTitle.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;


        [self.contentView addSubview:txtTitle];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)prevButtonPressed{
}

-(void)nextButtonPressed{
}

-(void)doneButtonPressed
{
    [self.txtTitle resignFirstResponder];
}
```

ViewController

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ItemCell *iCell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    iCell.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    iCell.txtTitle.text = [[myArr objectForKey@"section"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "Tag" to identify which textfield is selected. assign 'indexPath.row' to each text field. this is the only way to detect when you created it dynamically

Comment: I have set the tag in indexPath.row and in ItemCell done below. I can see the tag is asigned properly. But keyboard not moving. not sure why it's not working. -(void)prevButtonPressed{

    int nextTag = (int)self.txtTitle.tag + 1;
    NSLog(@"nextTag %d", nextTag);
    
    [[self viewWithTag:nextTag]  becomeFirstResponder];
}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by assigning tag to TextFiled when it's creating in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. I have define the uniq tag based on `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row`. I have assign `_nextTag` and `_prevTag` properties for the immediate next and previous `TextFiled` instances. Then in the CollectionView cell class, we can make the next or previous TextFiled `becomeFirstResponder` in the button action.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ItemCell *iCell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    iCell.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;

    // set uniuqe tag for each textfield
    //((section+1)(row)) eg: 11,12
    NSString *strTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%ld", indexPath.section+1,(long)indexPath.row];
    int tag = strTag.integerValue;
    iCell.txtTitle.tag = tag;

    int nextTag = tag + 1;
    int prevTag = tag -1;
}
```

CollectionViewCell class

```
-(void)nextButtonPressed{
    //int nextTag = (int)self.txtTitle.tag + 1;
    NSLog(@"nextTag %d", _nextTag);

    [[self.superview viewWithTag:_nextTag]  becomeFirstResponder];
}
```